# Measuring Audio Levels with FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've used FFmpeg in a little Automator script to bulk-analyze the audio levels of video files.

I'm trying to make sure that I'm using the best FFmpeg command. The two values I need reported are Integrated Loudness and True Peak. The following command reports mean(which I was taking as Loudness) and max(which I was taking as true peak):
`ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null`

The issue I'm having is that when I check the same file with Premier Pro, I'm getting slightly different results. Max/True Peak is the same, but Loudness/Mean is differrent. On the same file Premier is reporting -22.3 and FFmpeg -26.4.

I think I must be misappropriating mean to loudness. Is there a different command that would be more accurate?

Thank you a ton in advance!